# If $\chi$ irreducible complex character and normal $N \cap C_G (x) = 1$ with kernel not containing $N$, then $\chi(x)=0$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be finite group and $x\in G$.
If $\chi$ is irreducible complex character and normal $N\subset G$ with $N\cap C_G (x) =\{1\}$, then

(1) $|C_G (x)| \leq |C_{G/N} (xN)|$

(2)$\chi(x)=0$ if kernel does not contain $N$

I proved (1) by mapping y to yN, but I don't have any idea regarding (2).. (in my textbook,author suggests considering orthogonal relation expressing centralizer of x but it didn't help to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me use the bar convention. Note the canonical bijection
$$ \operatorname{Irr}(\overline{G}) \leftrightarrow
 \{\, \chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G) \mid N \subseteq \ker \chi \,\}. $$
From (1) and the orthogonal relation, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\lvert C_{\overline{G}}(\overline{x})\rvert
&\ge
\lvert C_G(x) \rvert
\\
&= \sum_{\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)} \lvert \chi(x) \rvert^2
\\
&\ge
 \sum_{\substack{\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)\\ N \subseteq \ker \chi}} \lvert \chi(x) \rvert^2
\\
&= 
\sum_{\psi \in \operatorname{Irr}(\overline{G})} \lvert \psi(\overline{x}) \rvert^2
\\
&=
\lvert C_{\overline{G}}(\overline{x})\rvert.
\end{align*}$$
Thus equality holds and we get the desired conclusion.

Comment: I got it. thanks!